# How is circuit integrity of ZK-rollups checked by the L1 contract?

Tags: scalability, zksnark, layer-2, zksync

TL;DR: what prevents an evil party forge a new evil operation (say mint 100 ETH for some account) and prove that the evil operation is executed correctly to the Layer 1 verifier contract?

---

I am reading the code of a ZK rollup's implementation called [zkSync](https://github.com/matter-labs/zksync). There are several Layer 2 [operations](https://github.com/matter-labs/zksync/blob/b55ab5a7ec1fddd6c236980a54bc59babbe0076e/core/lib/types/src/operations/mod.rs#L36) like `Transfer`, `Withdraw` and so on. They use [PLONK](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/953) as the zkSNARK backend, which generates a universal SRS and can be used to check any circuit up to length `n`. However, because of this flexibility, any circuit may be built and verified, not only the honest ones like `Transfer` defined by the original developers.

If I understand it correctly, with the PLONK protocol, the verifier (i.e. Layer 1 contract) is able to verify that *some* circuit is executed correctly, namely the input `x` and witness `w` satisfies specified constraints (e.g. after a series of operations contained in `w`, the state merkle tree root matches [`new_root`](https://github.com/matter-labs/zksync/blob/master/docs/protocol.md#block-state-transition-circuit) contained in `x`). But it cannot check whether the circuit is constructed honestly. In order to get `polylog(n)` complexity in verification time, the prover cannot list all operations done in the circuit, which may contain an evil operation. So why cannot one create a new operation and cheat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [PLONK paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/953) again, I noticed that $q_m$, $q_l$, $q_r$ etc are preprocessed and fixed as input to the verifier, which specify the circuit. That is to say, the circuit is not provided by the prover, but pre-computed by the verifier. So it is secure.

I haven't checked the source code, but I guess these circuit specification polynomials (actually their commitments) are hard-coded in the solidity program on contract setup.